# How do I add the date a blog post was created in place of a bullet point under list-style-type?

Tags: css, html

Hey I am learning how to create a basic webpage using HTML5 & CSS and I was wondering how I could add the date e.g. "23 Oct 2013" before each blog post link in place of where the bullet point would be when using list-style-type in CSS. For example:

23 Oct 2013 » How to code in HTML

Would be an example of how it would look like in a browser, bearing in mind that it is a list?

Thanks

Comment: Use the `:before` pseudo element.

Comment: Would this automatically post the date when I add a post? Or would I have to add the date every time? I'd like it to just post the date the post was created?

Comment: No - it wouldn't. You would need a dynamic script to achieve something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be a true working blog, the other answers would have you dynamically create css and have a class or id for each date you wanted displayed. It would be better to set `list-style-type: none` and have your back-end load the dates and post titles, not have it write your css.

HTML/PSEUDOCODE:

```
<ul id="blog">
    {% for post in blog %}
    <li class="post">{{ post.date }} » {{ post.title }}</li>
    {% end for %}
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#blog {
    list-style-type: none
}
```

This way it would look like:

> 23 Oct 2013 » How to code in CSS
>
> 19 Oct 2013 » How to code in HTML

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful, sorry to be a noob but how exactly would I load the date from there?

Comment: You would need a server-side language, or I guess a javascript connection to an API. Simplest answer is, with just html and css, you can't.

Answer (score 1):

By using the CSS `:before` selector.

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/LJrag/)** is a working example.

HTML:

```
<ul id="blog">
    <li>How to code in HTML</li>
    <li>How to code in CSS</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#blog li:before
{ 
    content:"23 Oct 2013 » ";
}
```

Comment: Thanks but would this automatically post the date when I add a post? Or would I have to add the date every time? I'd like it to just post the date the post was created?

Comment: @Isaac You can not do that with CSS/HTML only. You need to grab a date when post is created from your publishing platform / CMS, and then inject it in to that list. Are you using WordPress?

Comment: No I am still in the process of finishing it but thank you, I didnt know that.